# get logon as of services running on remote machine

Tags: c#, windows-services, wmi

Hi I would like to get list of all services and their 'Log On AS' on a remote machine (in network, using computername or IP) using C#.

I think it can be achieved using WMI but don't have any idea how(i haven't used wmi before)?.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `StartName` property of the [Win32_Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394418%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) class.

Try this sample

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Management;
using System.Text;

namespace GetWMI_Info
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                string ComputerName = "localhost";
                ManagementScope Scope;                

                if (!ComputerName.Equals("localhost", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) 
                {
                    ConnectionOptions Conn = new ConnectionOptions();
                    Conn.Username  = "";
                    Conn.Password  = "";
                    Conn.Authority = "ntlmdomain:DOMAIN";
                    Scope = new ManagementScope(String.Format("\\\\{0}\\root\\CIMV2", ComputerName), Conn);
                }
                else
                    Scope = new ManagementScope(String.Format("\\\\{0}\\root\\CIMV2", ComputerName), null);

                Scope.Connect();
                ObjectQuery Query = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Service");
                ManagementObjectSearcher Searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(Scope, Query);

                foreach (ManagementObject WmiObject in Searcher.Get())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0,-35} {1,-40}","Name",WmiObject["Name"]);// String
                    Console.WriteLine("{0,-35} {1,-40}","StartName",WmiObject["StartName"]);// String

                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Exception {0} Trace {1}",e.Message,e.StackTrace));
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to exit");
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can this be achieved without using WMI?

Comment: Yes, you can try the [ServiceController](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.aspx) class

Comment: I did, but it doesn't give "log on as" or I couldn't find. Can you please help me with that?

Comment: In your question you ask about using the WMI to do this task. IF you want to use the `ServiceController` class instead accept the answer y make a new question.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is much easier way, you can find it in the registry in the service details (SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\service name) 
And there you have the object name